# Как программно изменить стартовую страницу?

Tags: c#, авторизация, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windowsphone

У меня есть 2 страницы:
1.MainPage.xaml - окно авторизации
2.Page2.xaml - страница куда попадает пользователь после успешного прохождения авторизации на MainPage.xaml
Есть локальная база данных SQLite, где храниться информация о пользователях приложения, в том числе и то кто в последний раз был авторизован.
Есть get_user_auth() - возвращает ID последнего пользователя прошедшего авторизацию.
Есть метод который в случае если есть авторизованный пользователь, переходит со страницы MainPage на Page2

```
void auto_auth()
        {
            int globaluserid = MS.get_user_auth();
            if (globaluserid > 0)
                {
                    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), globaluserid);
                }
        }
```

### ВОПРОС:

Как сделать что бы приложение запускала вместо стартовой страницы MainPage страницу Page2 при условии что MS.get_user_auth()>0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Свою задачу решил следующим образом

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
            this.Loaded += (a, b) => { auto_auth(); };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы делаете для Windows Phone 8.0, то стартовая страница всегда MainPage.xaml. Если вы делаете для Windows Phone 8.1, то в файле App.xaml.cs можно изменить установить любую стартовую страницу.